# How to Run container from docker compose after 1 hour

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have 10 container in docker compose.
I want 9 containers to start working when i `up` the docker compose and allow docker-compose to run the 10th container after 1 hour of time.

Currently its running all containers at once.

How i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Compose doesn’t directly have this functionality.  (Kubernetes doesn’t either, though it does have the ability to run a short-lived container at a specified time of day.)

Probably the best workaround to the problem as you’ve stated it is to use a tool like **at**(1) to run an additional container at a later time

```
at +1h docker run ...
```

My experience has generally been that it can get a little messy to depend on starting and stopping Docker containers for workflow management.  You may be better off starting a pool of workers against some job queue system like RabbitMQ and injecting a job after an hour, or using a language-native scheduled-task library in your application, and just always start every container every time.